# Reading string data into haskell data type?

Tags: haskell

Short-and-sweet, I have a text file that looks like this:

```
ID1|ID2|DATE|SUM
0|0|20/03/2014|100.00
0|1|20/04/2014|99.00
```

I have a custom data type that looks like this:

```
data DBData = DBData { id1   :: Int
                     , id2   :: Int
                     , date  :: String
                     , sum   :: Int
                     } deriving (Eq, Read, Show)
```

How do I get this into that?

What I have been toying with so far is using something like this:

```
parseRow :: [String] -> DBData 
parseRow = let (id1:id2:date:sum) = (splitWhen (=='|')) s
                i = read id1
             in DBData {id1 = i}
```

But I can't seem to get the syntax right ...

related to my other post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477554/using-splitwhen-to-split-string-by-delimiter-and-trying-to-figure-out-how-to-sto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Haskell, all data constructors and concrete types must begin with a capital letter:

```
data DbData = DbData ...
```

Also, if you want to use the `read` method to read in something in a custom format like that, you must make a the data type an instance of `Read`:

```
instance Read DbData where
  read s = ...
```

Inside the instance definition you can define `read` as you would any other Haskell function.

Also, the proper `let` syntax (outside a `do` block) is

```
let binding = val
in
... body ...
```

When you create a data type, you (usually) make one or more constructors that you can use to make values of that type. Here is an example that is sort of similar to yours

```
data Example = Example { a :: Int
                       , b :: Char
                       , c :: String
                       }
```

We can make a value of type `Example` using the `Example` constructor (note that these don't *need* to have the same name):

```
exampleValue :: Example
example = Example 1 'z' "abcdef"
```

Comment: Any chance you could take that a step further, but struggling for a while trying to figure out how to get the data populated, don't mind how ... this was just a suggestion. But I don't understand what you mean by needing an instance and I don't see how that would allow me to parse our the pieces I need .. nor how to use it after

Comment: @JSchwartz Right now, the best thing to do would be to ignore the `Read` instance stuff altogether and try to define a normal function that reads the data from in that format into the data type. Use the `DbData` data constructor to construct a value of that type using the data that you've read in.

Comment: @JSchwartz I added a little bit of information about using data constructors. That is the main thing that you are missing in your code other than the syntactic issues.

Comment: not 100% sure I follow (because I can't seem to get it right), can you take a look at my updated post (new code) and let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Error I get is `parse error on input =` from my READ line

Comment: @JSchwartz Add an `s` to the argument list for `parseRow` and line `i` up with the `(` in the line above it. `let` definitions need to be lined up in this way. Also, I'd suggest removing `Read` from the `deriving` list. It won't help you read it in this case and it might lead to confusion later. By the way, you don't need parentheses around `splitWhen`. You also don't need to individually name each result of `read`. You could just replace `i` with `read id1` in the field initialization.

Comment: You are on to something - damn indents. ...but for the (s) in the argument list for parseRow, where exactly? I already have [String] defined for that (s) no? not sure I see the issue

Comment: @JSchwartz `s` is undefined. You need to tell Haskell you want to name the argument `s`: `parseRow s = ...`. Also, I suspect you want your function type to be `String -> DBData`. `String` is a synonym for `[Char]` (so it's the exact same as `[Char]`).

Comment: I think I have just been struggling with this for to long but I don't see it, you are correct that (s) is not defined (getting that error now) but I can't seem to figure out where exactly to put it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59907/discussion-between-david-young-and-jschwartz).